# How to Create a Custom Reader Class in Java

Tags: java, wrapper, decorator, java-io

I want create my `CustomReader` Class by subclassing the `java.io.Reader` class. My `CustomReader` will wrap around another `BufferedReader` which the actual input is read and from which my own translation of the input is added and returned to my caller. (Is it called the Decorator pattern?)

The javadoc says only `close` and `read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)` of the `Reader` class are abstract methods but the others are not. But what kind of default implementation can I expect from these other non-abstract methods inherited from `java.io.Reader`? For example, if someone call my `read()` which is inherited from the `Reader` class, would it call my implementation of `read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)` to get the input? Also how do the standard `Reader`'s `ready()` method determine its return value? Since it is not abstract and I don't have to provide an implementation.

Do I really need to forward all the inherited methods from `Reader` to the `BufferedReader` I wrap around - be it abstract or not?

Answer (score 0):

> what kind of default implementation can I expect from these other non-abstract methods inherited from java.io.Reader?

You can expect an implementation that respects the contract in the javadoc, provided that the methods you override also respect the contract.

> For example, if someone call my read() which is inherited from the Reader class, would it call my implementation of read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) to get the input?

Yes. Here's the implementation of read():

```
    char cb[] = new char[1];
    if (read(cb, 0, 1) == -1)
        return -1;
    else
        return cb[0];
```

> how do the standard Reader's ready() method determine its return value?

It always returns false.

> Do I really need to forward all the inherited methods from Reader to the BufferedReader I wrap around

You need to make sure they do what they're supposed to. But since they will already delegate to your implementation of the abstract method, which itself delegates to the wrapped reader, it will probably not be necessary to override them.

My advice: don't hesitate to read the source code of Reader. And write unit tests for all the methods, inherited or not, of your custom reader.

Comment: overriding and then delegating is safer and better advice though. No?

Comment: Delegating to what? If you delegate to your own read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) method, then your implementation is the same as the one in Reader. And if you delegate to the wrapped reader, then your custom reader doesn't add any custom behavior anymore. But it's quite pointless to discuss the best way without knowing what your custom reader is supposed to do anyway.